# Add existing instance (object) to unity

Tags: c#, unity-container, inversion-of-control

i want to add an existing object to my unity container registered to a specific interface,

so when i resolve the interface i get that existing object (it's used for testing, and the object holds a lot of XML data, and for eacht test case i want to use another object).

I do it like this:

```
public static void RegisterInstance<T>(T instance)
        {

            container.RegisterInstance<T>(instance);
        }
```

where `container` is my UnityContainer.
This code is in a static class called `IoCContainer`

My call then is:

```
IoCContainer.RegisterInstance<IConfigurationRepository>(new MockConfigurationRepository(XML));
```

this seems to work, but when i later add a new instance, the old one seems to held in memory by Unity.
So when i later on want to register object B in stead of object B (during testing) and later on register C , unity correctly resolves C but it keeps B and A in memory (and they are quite large, that't why i noticed.

Is there a way to remove A and B from Unity's memory?

Comment: Are you sure that unity is the one holding the reference?  It could be some other part of your code, or perhaps the objects just haven't been garbage collected yet.

Comment: quite sure, because when i set my internal variable container to NULL and instantiate a new one then the memory useage drops

Comment: Are you sure the objects haven't been released by Unity but the garbage collector just hasn't cleaned them up yet? You used the word 'seems' to be held in memory. A memory profiler will reveal the answer for sure.

Comment: you're right, i'm not absolutely sure, i used the word 'seems' because when i utterly destroy the unity container, the memory gets freed. Do you think Unity probably doesn't have this behaviour?

Comment: @jdk: i'm not familiair with 'memory profiler'. Is it a separate tool, and what can be seen in it?

Comment: About profiling see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming) and then http://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&qscrl=1&q=.net+memory+profiler& Might be worth opening a separate SO question to find a profiler, if such a question is not already answered somewhere.  For example the product http://memprofiler.com/ allows you to view: `The profiler presents real-time information about all .NET instance allocations performed on the garbage collected heap and all instances that reside on the heap.`

Comment: And sometimes the garbage collector doesn't kick in until the application has exited because it didn't deem the operation worthwhile before then. What you call a lot of data the GC might not.  Also, just from my own experience, a garbage collected program, although having been reduced in size, isn't necessarily reflected as such as the OS level (i.e. Windows Task Manager counts) - that level of monitoring mem usage usually doesn't provide good info. That's why a profiler tool would be good - because it will give you direct and immediate insight into what's referenced and what's not in the pgm

Comment: @jdk i think i know what you're saying, but i see memory growing and my pc going slower and slower...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what seems to be the problem is not that Unity holds the object, but an object created in the app, which uses the object, is keeping the GC from collecting it.

So this not realy an answer, but i didn't see any delete button for my question....